# Finding $(a,b)\,,a>b$ such that $\int^b_a(6-x-x^2)\,dx$ is maximum

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

> Find 2 numbers $(a,b)$ $a>b$ such that we get the maximum value of the integral
>   $\int^b_a(6-x-x^2)dx$.

attempt:

I tried this:

$f'(x) = 0 $

$ 6-x-x^2 = 0$

$ (x_1,x_2)=(2,-3)$

$(a,b) = (2,-3)$

$\int^b_a(6-x-x^2)dx = \int^2_{-3}(6-x-x^2)dx = 38.83$

Is it the correct answer? $(a,b) = (2,-3)$?

Thanks!!

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811907/how-to-find-max-int-ab-left-frac34-x-x2-right-dx-over-all-pos.

Comment: $\int_2^{-3} f dx$ is negative. Did you mean $(a,b) = (-3, 2)$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. Note that $f(x)=(6-x-x^2)=-(x-2)(x+3)$ so in order the get the maximum value of $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ with $a<b$, it suffices to integrate over the interval $[a,b]$ where the integrand is non-negative that is $[-3,2]$.